# How to clear cache in Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am doing some benchmark tests for Facebook's Yarn. For this, I need to clear my global Yarn cache.

Is there a command available for this? I have force-removed my `~/.yarn-cache` folder, but this seems to be quite manual.

Answer (score 830, accepted):

Ok I found out the answer myself. Much like `npm cache clean`, Yarn also has its own

```
yarn cache clean
```

Comment: In case others miss this, be certain to run this from the user account running yarn. 

In my case, I was trying to clean a continuous integration server with a different Windows account than the one our project builds on, and it wasn't removing files until I realized I needed to run it from that account.

Answer (score 157):

Run `yarn cache clean`.

---

Run `yarn help cache`  in your bash, and you will see:

> Usage: yarn cache [ls|clean] [flags]
>
> Options:
>     -h, --help                  output usage information
>     -V, --version               output the version number
>     --offline
>     --prefer-offline
>     --strict-semver
>     --json
>     --global-folder [path]
>     --modules-folder [path]     rather than installing modules into the node_modules folder relative to the cwd, output them here
>     --packages-root [path]      rather than storing modules into a global packages root, store them here
>     --mutex [type][:specifier]  use a mutex to ensure only one yarn instance is executing
>
> Visit http://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache for documentation about this command.

Comment: That is the same answer from @nikjohn

Comment: @LeoCaseiro this is what could be called "race conditions" XD

Comment: how to clean single package?

Comment: @EliavLouski `yarn cache clean package-name` see documentation for details: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/cache#toc-yarn-cache-clean (it's missing in the documentation of Yarn 2 though, but hopefully, it's still supported).

Comment: @MarcoOttina This answer is an entire day later though..

Answer (score 113):

Also note that the cached directory is located in `~/.yarn-cache/`:

`yarn cache clean`: cleans that directory

`yarn cache list`: shows the list of cached dependencies

`yarn cache dir`: prints out the path of your cached directory

Comment: its not always in `~/.yarn-cache/`

Comment: On my Mac the cache directory is `~/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6` as reported by the `yarn cache dir` command.

Comment: I have both. `yarn cache dir` returns `~/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6`. But `~/.yarn-cache/` is 2.8GB and hasn't been updated since January 2018. `yarn cache clean` _**does not work**_ on `~/.yarn-cache/`. It has to be manually deleted.

Cache location seems to be a tumultuous subject https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/search?q=.yarn-cache&type=Commits

Comment: On my Mac (M1), I found some yarn global modules sitting at `~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules` as well.

Comment: ERROR: cache is not COMMAND nor fully qualified CLASSNAME.

Answer (score 43):

In addition to the answer, `$ yarn cache clean` removes all libraries from cache. If you want to remove a specific lib's cache run `$ yarn cache dir` to get the right yarn cache directory path for your OS, then `$ cd` to that directory and remove the folder with the `name` + `version` of the lib you want to cleanup.

Comment: ERROR: cache is not COMMAND nor fully qualified CLASSNAME.

Answer (score 1):

1. To clear the cache, run the following command:

   `yarn cache clean`   → This command will clear the entire Yarn cache for you
2. To clear the cache selectively:

   `yarn cache clean packagename` → for example: `yarn cache clean react`

To list out the cache for all the packages currently cached, run the command below:

`yarn cache list` → From here, you can choose to selectively remove packages.