# Yarn -Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying

Tags: yarnpkg

I have been trying to do the quick start guide for Vue (CLI) but kept getting this error

```
Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
Info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
```

and I see all answer in the same issue in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508364/yarn-there-appears-to-be-trouble-with-your-network-connection-retrying)
, but doesn't fix. ( OS: windows )

Comment: Are you able to use curl from that prompt? I am wondering if your internet connection is having issues?

Comment: @TimothyDalton yes and my npm work completely

Comment: Can you also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991508/how-to-clear-cache-in-yarn#:~:text=In%20addition%20to%20the%20answer,lib%20you%20want%20to%20cleanup. ?

Comment: I did that, but doesn't fix .
I uninstall and install but doesn't fix @TimothyDalton

Comment: Which yarn command are you trying?

Comment: yarn global add @vue/cli
  and yarn and yarn init and yarn add <somepackages>

Comment: Can you delete yarn.lock and try `yarn install --network-timeout 1000000` ?

Comment: I do this but it does not work, I continued my project with npm and
I was disappointed with the YARN. I did everything I could but it didn't work out, it's really weird. I deleted the yarn once and reinstalled it, but we still have a problem @TimothyDalton

Comment: I had the same issue tried everything but only thing that worked was going back to npm.

Comment: I change my os to ubuntu :((( @yudhiesh

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had added a [private npm repository](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-private-packages-in-a-ci-cd-workflow) into `~/.npmrc` in the past, so yarn try to find the package in that repository.
And unfortunately the repository's no longer available, that makes yarn couldn't find the package.
Solution:

```
rm ~/.npmrc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I reset my windows and then work . I think in this file I don't have ~/.npmrc file

Answer (score 3):

In my case I've tried to build app inside Node Docker container. Adding option --network=host was the solution in my case.

> docker build --network=host --progress=plain .