# yarn cache size on Mac OS too big

Tags: yarnpkg

I just used Clean My Mac's space lens feature to understand what was eating my disk space and I found this under ~/Libary/Caches

[image]

Even with the biggest imagination, I can't think at a reason for that folder being so big, is it possible to safely (and periodically) delete this folder?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can delete that directory (or run `yarn cache clean` -- see [How to clear cache in Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991508/how-to-clear-cache-in-yarn)).

Yarn, by default caches the packages it downloads (including different versions). If you delete this cache, the main side-effect that you'll see is it may take longer to run a `yarn install` because it will need to fetch the necessary packages again.

Comment: it took a lot of time, but it worked, thank you :-)

Comment: Same thing should be applied to `.npm` caches with `npm cache clean --force`, as it grows to ridiculous sizes.