# Yarn 3 nodeLinker: node-modules

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

Why does yarn create a ".yarn/cache" directory when using `node-modules`?

My `.yarnrc.yml` is:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

Answer (score 1):

`node-modules` linker doesn't mean it's bound to `node_modules` path (hyphen vs underline) but chooses an algorithm of how to install packages as far as I've understood.

Using e.g. 'pnp' instead of 'node-linker', then you don't need the `node_modules` at all.

Yarn generates a `.pnp.cjs` file:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

This approach is called **Plug & Play** I assume because it speeds up the installation process dramatically.

All this and more found:
https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp

---

I'm using `yarn` or its alias `yarn install` relatively often.

Yarn will check its cache for already downloaded packages and install them directly from there, which is much faster than downloading them from the registry.

You find a link at the bottom to read all the benefits like:

> The offline cache is a feature that allows Yarn to work just fine even should the network go down for any reason - whether it's because your employer didn't pay the utility bill or because the place where your packages are hosted becomes unavailable. It's also a critical part of Zero-Installs and doesn't store more than a single file for each package - making it suitable for being stored within a repository, as we actually do in the Yarn repository itself.

There are additional benefits in separating the cache from `node_modules`:

- .gitignore `node_modules` but share the cache, in general I don't like to share the cache, but Yarn's cache is pretty strong doing so if you really want it
- use a `.yarnrc.yml` file to either use `enableGlobalCache` or set a specific path setting `cacheFolder`

Those are just examples.

Try out `yarn help cache` to see yourself what you can do with your cache.

Where I got some of the infos:

- [How to clear cache in Yarn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991508/how-to-clear-cache-in-yarn)
- https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc
- https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache (Quote from here)